# compare NSSet in Predicate for Fetchrequest Xcode Swift OSX Core Data

Tags: swift, xcode, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have two `NSManagedObject` like

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var firstname: String;
    @NSManaged var lastname: String;
    @NSManaged var code: String;
    @NSManaged var position: Int16;
    @NSManaged var lasttime: NSDate;
    @NSManaged var isvip: Int16;    
    @NSManaged var changeposition: NSSet;   
}


class ChangePosition: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var person:Person
    @NSManaged var code: String;
    @NSManaged var from: Int16;
    @NSManaged var to: Int16;
    @NSManaged var time: NSDate;   
}
```

so I have one Person with many `ChangePosition` as `NSSet`. Each `ChangePosition` has a `NSDate`.

now I want to try to fetch the one `ChangePosition` from a Person with the highest `NSDate`. Which predicate construct can I use for this?

Answer (score -1):

so my actually workflow for this is this one

```
let fetchReqPerson = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person");
        //fetchReq.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY personchangeposition.time == maxElement(personchangeposition.time)")



        do {

            let fetchResult = try self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchReqPerson)

            for managedObject in fetchResult {

                var bigTime:PersonChangePosition?


                for changes in (managedObject as! Person).personchangeposition {



                    if (changes as! PersonChangePosition).time.compare(_date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {

                        if bigTime == nil {
                            bigTime = changes as! PersonChangePosition
                        } else {

                            if (changes as! PersonChangePosition).time.compare(bigTime!.time) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
                                bigTime = changes as! PersonChangePosition;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

                if bigTime != nil {
                    //print("bigTime: ",bigTime!.time, "to: ",bigTime!.to)

                    self.fetchResultPerson.append(bigTime!)
                }



            }


            self.fetchForRecord = self.fetchResultPerson;

            //print("fetchResult fetchResultPerson: ",fetchResultPerson.count)


            } catch let fetchError as NSError {

            print("Fetching error: ",fetchError)
            }



            //

            switch(self.areaSegementControl.selectedSegment){


            case 0: self.fetchForRecord = try self.fetchForRecord.filter({$0.to != 4})
            break;

            case 1: self.fetchForRecord = try self.fetchForRecord.filter({$0.to == 1 || $0.to == 3})
            break;

            case 2: self.fetchForRecord = try self.fetchForRecord.filter({$0.to == 2})
            break;

            default:
            break;

            }
```

but of course, its rather slow .... not really good